# DFA accept 00 as a substring

Tags: finite-automata, regular-expressions, substrings

How can design this question if we have an equation like that 
={wxw | w={0,1}* , x=00} accept 00 it means not contain 000,001,100, but accept all these {00,1001,110011,001000001.....}. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Bad English, which is irritating but understandable on the ground of second language. Misleading question, since there is no DFA accepting a non-regular language. No sign of work shown, which is not welcomed on this site.

Answer (score 0):

as said above the language is non-regular , since there is no way a Finite automata can compare the existence of two same string in a single compound string. which is the case here. 
its is advised that please show the efforts that you made apart from asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

After processing k 1’s in a row, the shortest string that would be accepted is 00, followed by k 1’s. This shows that after processing k 1’s or k’ 1s for k != k’, we are in different states. Which means there is an infinite number of states, therefore no DFA.

In general for any prefix u there is a set of suffixes v such that uv is in the language. Each such set is a state; if there are infinitely many different sets of suffixes leading to an accepted string then there is no DFA.